# Bootstrap 5 > change styling of the navbar when expanded on smaller devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

First time posting a question here so please be kind :)

I added the following script to change the css of my navbar when scrolling.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
let header = document.querySelector(".navbar");
let windowPosition = window.scrollY > 0;
header.classList.toggle("change-bg-nav", windowPosition);});
```

This is the CSS for the class

```
.change-bg-nav {
box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.9) !important;
backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);}
```

Effect works great, when I scroll on any device size the css of the navbar changes as expected. Now I'm looking to achieve the same effect when I'm on a smaller device and click on the hamburger icon to expand the menu ** but without having scrolled**. I've tried mediaqueries but that doesn't give me the desired result. Any suggestions for how to approach this?

The code for my nav

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light px-3 mb-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand name</a>
                <button
                    class="navbar-toggler"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html#contact-me">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-nav social-media">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="nav-link social"><i class="fab fa-twitter px-1"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="nav-link social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in px-1"></i
                        ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the Navbar Collapse events to toggle the `change-bg-nav` class...

```
let header = document.querySelector(".navbar");
header.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', function () {
     header.classList.toggle("change-bg-nav");
})
header.addEventListener('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
     header.classList.toggle("change-bg-nav");
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/7AXPT20HSL

Comment: That actually works, thank you! There's something strange with the interaction when you combine scrolling on a mobile device and then click the hamburger icon, release it and scroll back up again. Find it actually behaves more intuitively if you use 'add' instead of 'toggle' on show.bs and then 'remove' on hide.bs. Still trying to get my head around the difference between 'add' and 'toggle'.

Answer (score -1):

For mobile devices, I think you should use another strategy.
ie.

```
if(hamburger.clicked) {
// add bg navber color.
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I thought about that but in combination with the scrolling and depending on the order of the actions, it still doesn't behave like I want so decided to ditch the idea of the nav being fixed on top and just manipulate the css from the hamburger being visible or not. Will come back to this when I find a better solution.